# Azure New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy fails with error "The specified resource does not exist"

Tags: powershell, azure, iaas

I'm attempting to enable IaaS VM backup in Azure using a Recovery Services Vault and it fails when attempting to create a new Protection Policy using Azure `New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy`.

The script has worked for a previous subscription and VMs, so I'm unclear why it doesn't work for this subscription.  I've run `Azure New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Debug` which returns the below additional information, unfortunately that's not enough to highlight and resolve the problem either:

```
"error": {
  "code": "InvalidRestApiParameter",
  "message": "stampId parameter is invalid.\r\nPlease provide a valid stampId",
  "target": null,
  "details": null,
  "innerError": null
}
```

Here's the code which attempts to create the Protection Policy:

```
# Create Retention Policy object.  Has to be modified from existing 'default' values provided by Azure
$RetPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRetentionPolicyObject -WorkloadType "AzureVM"

$BackupTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().Date.AddHours(23)

$Day = $true
$DayTime = $BackupTime
$DayRet = 7

$Week = $true
$WeekDay = 'Sunday'
$WeekTime = $BackupTime
$WeekRet = 5

$Month = $true
$MonthType = 'Daily'
$MonthTime = $BackupTime
$MonthDay = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Date = 0;
        IsLast = $true;
    }
$MonthRet = 3

$Year = $false


$RetPol.IsDailyScheduleEnabled = $Day
$RetPol.DailySchedule.DurationCountInDays = $DayRet
$RetPol.DailySchedule.RetentionTimes[0] = $DayTime

$RetPol.IsWeeklyScheduleEnabled = $Week
$RetPol.WeeklySchedule.DaysOfTheWeek = $WeekDay
$RetPol.WeeklySchedule.DurationCountInWeeks = $WeekRet
$RetPol.WeeklySchedule.RetentionTimes[0] = $WeekTime

$RetPol.IsMonthlyScheduleEnabled = $Month
$RetPol.MonthlySchedule.RetentionScheduleFormatType = $MonthType
$RetPol.MonthlySchedule.RetentionScheduleDaily.DaysOfTheMonth = $MonthDay
$RetPol.MonthlySchedule.DurationCountInMonths = $MonthRet
$RetPol.MonthlySchedule.RetentionScheduleWeekly = $null
$RetPol.MonthlySchedule.RetentionTimes[0] = $MonthTime

$RetPol.IsYearlyScheduleEnabled = $Year
$RetPol.YearlySchedule = $null


# Create Schedule Policy object.
$SchPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupSchedulePolicyObject -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
$SchPol.ScheduleRunFrequency = "Daily"
$SchPol.ScheduleRunDays = $null
$SchPol.ScheduleRunTimes[0] = $BackupTime


#Create the new Backup Policy
$BackupPolicy = New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -WorkloadType AzureVM -Name 'MyPolicy' -RetentionPolicy $RetPol -SchedulePolicy $SchPol
```

Any help or thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Deleted and re-created the Recovery Services Vault via PowerShell

**Full Description**
Turned-out that something had previously gone wrong with the creation of the Recovery Services Vault, which wasn't clear when I'd run `New-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault` but had resulted in the following view of the RSV when opened via the Portal:

[image]

The RSV wouldn't delete via the portal so I had to use `Remove-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault` to remove it.  I then re-created it, which resolved the error and allowed me to backup the VMs